# Elixir: How to alias a module that just imports a load of functions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to put my Accounts context functions into their own files, then import them into the context so that I can alias the `App.Accounts` in my controllers and use the functions that were imported into the context.

See below for the rough setup that I am after.

```
defmodule App.Accounts.UserAPI do
  alias App.Accounts.User

  def get_user!(id), do: User.get!(User, id) end

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    import App.Accounts.UserAPI
end

defmodule App.Accounts do
  alias App.Accounts.UserAPI
  use UserAPI
end

defmodule AppWeb.UserController do
  alias App.Accounts

  IO.inspect Accounts.module_info
  # [
    # module: Ev2.Accounts, 
    # exports: [__info__: 1, module_info: 0, module_info: 1],
    # attributes: [vsn: [234644860605005629180170678994286615550]],
    # compile: [options: [:debug_info], version: '7.0.4',
    # source: '/Users/.../accounts.ex'],
    # native: false,
    # md5: <<176, 134, 244, 210, 70, 244, 89, 41, 130, 7, 134, 109, 55, 131, 27, 254>>
  # ]
  def index(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    Accounts.get_user(id) # Accounts.get_user/1 is not defined
  end
end
```

I currently have it working by wrapping the entire `App.UserAPI` in `__using__` macro and quotes, but that feels verbose and wrapping in quote seems to prevent me from calling utility functions from within the `UserAPI`.

Why do the `UserAPI` functions not appear in the `Accounts.module_info` exports? 
 And what is the "right" way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that imported functions are not exported by a module. They're only available in the context of the import. You want to re-export imported functions. There are two ways I can think of.

1. What you're currently doing according to your description: define all functions in a quote block in `__using__`:

   ```
   defmodule App.Accounts.UserAPI do
     defmacro __using__(_) do
       quote do
         alias App.Accounts.User

         def get_user!(id), do: User.get!(User, id) end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use `defdelegate` to define a function which just calls another function:

   ```
   defmodule App.Accounts.UserAPI do
     def get_user!(id), do: User.get!(User, id) end

     defmacro __using__(_) do
       quote do
         defdelegate :get_user!(id), to: App.Accounts.UserAPI
       end
     end
   end
   ```

In both cases, a `use App.Accounts.UserAPI` will do what you want.